# Sign APK using credentials from Windows crypto store?

Tags: multi-device-hybrid-apps

Using Visual Studio 2013 Update 3 running on Win 8.1, I have successfully built a signed APK by specifying values for key.store, key.alias, etc., in the `res/cert/android/ant.properties` file. Now I want to sign the APK with credentials retrieved from the native Windows crypto store -- i.e., pass `-storetype Windows-MY` to the jarsigner tool. How do I do this using MDHA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing more research, I've concluded that the only way to do what I've described *within the scope of the Android ant build* is to somehow redefine the `-release-sign` target in `${sdk.dir}/tools/ant/build.xml`. I say "somehow" because I can't figure out how to inject my own rules into `bld/Release/platforms/android/custom_rules.xml`.

On the other hand, I could write my own target in the MDHA project file to execute the `jarsigner` and `zipalign` tools. The downside of this approach is that it requires me to encode in the project file the locations of these tools and the target APK file.